# How to add the 'u' prefix to a list or string?

Tags: python, string, unicode

I've been having some unicode issues and realized (a bit too late, admittedly) that adding the 'u' prefix to a string did the trick:

> > print (u'No\xebl')
> >
> > > Noël

However, I am working with a lot of strings and lists of strings, so I need to add that prefix to each one (say, I want to add "u" to "string", with string = 'No\xebl'). I've tried different ways:

> > print "u"+"'"+string
> >
> > print unicode(string)
> >
> > print "u" + string
> >
> > print repr(unicode(m)) #Doing so does add the prefix 'u', but adds an extra "\" to the string and no longer fixes the problem
> >
> > > u'No\xebl'

The list goes on but you get the gist. Basically, I was wondering if there was a way to do exactly the same as print (u'No\xebl'), but with any variable string without having to actually write the string down.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where do these strings come from? If you wrote `'No\xebl'` in your source code, stick a `u` there in your source code. If you're getting these strings from some external source, like a file or a web page, you will need to determine the source's encoding and decode it.

Comment: At least your heart's in the right place, even if you haven't completely figured it out. http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/

Comment: Also: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Answer (score 2):

`\xeb` encodes `ë` in [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). To convert from bytes to a Unicode string, use the `.decode()` method.

```
string.decode('iso-8859-1')
```

That being said: where is this data coming from? Do you know it's always ISO 8859-1, or may it be encoded differently? Why is it in bytes instead of a Unicode string already? Answers to these questions may allow for better solutions.

Comment: I'm getting: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: @alfasin - You are using Python3.  Lynn Bou Nassif is using Python2. This answer is directed at Python2.

Comment: True. @ephemient can you please expend your answer to cover python3?

Comment: @alfasin Python 3 defaults to Unicode strings: `'No\xebl'` in Python 3 is equivalent to `u'No\xebl'` in Python 2. The same method works in Python 3 from `bytes`. `b'No\xebl'.decode('iso-8859-1')`

Comment: @ephemient Thank you so much! Most of the data comes from a web scraping project, but from the looks of it, most of it is ISO 8859-1, but I don't know why it's that way :/ I've tried the decoding method and it seems to be working for individual strings (say, if I store 'No\xebl' in "string"), but when it comes to lists, it's not working 
>> for i in list_string:
>>i. decode('iso-8859-1')
And just doesn't change anything. Any idea why?

Comment: @LynnBouNassif Much (but not all) web content is in ISO 8859-1. Sometimes the server will specify the encoding in the `Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1` header. Sometimes the content will contain a `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">` or `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">` tag (which is interesting because you don't know the right charset to read before reading it). Sometimes there is neither or it's wrong and you have to guess. Welcome to the world wide web.

Comment: @LynnBouNassif WhatWG suggests this algorithm for detecting character encoding: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#determining-the-character-encoding. It is quite complex. Depending on your data set, you may want to use simpler heuristics.

Answer (score -1):

do this;

```
tempvariabel = u''
realvariabel = tempvariabel + somevariabelcontainUnicode
```

it's return error when you want to print it, but it's ready to write on file or database